# Regex: Check IP address against user input with wildcard

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have a list named `IpAddressList` with some IP addresses like 192.168.0.5 and so on.

The user can search the list for a given IP address, also by using the wildcard *

**This is my method:**

```
public bool IpAddressMatchUserInput(String userInput, String ipAddressFromList)
{
    Regex regex = new Regex("");

    Match match = regex.Match(ipAddressFromList);

    return match.Success;
}
```

The `userInput` can be for example:

- 192.168.0.*
- 192.
- 192.168.0.5
- 192.*.0.*

In all cases the method should return true, but I don't know how to use Regex in combination with the `userInput`and how the regex should look.

Comment: Is this a valid input 192.*.0.* ?

Comment: @user3185569 Yes it is :)

Comment: check answer below.

Comment: What is the separator in your IP address list string?

Comment: The method is called in a foreach loop for each IP address (parameter: ipAddressFromList)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this should work (covering also `192.*.0.*`):

```
public static bool IpAddressMatchUserInput(String userInput, String ipAddressFromList)
{
    Regex rg = new Regex(userInput.Replace("*", @"\d{1,3}").Replace(".", @"\."));

    return rg.IsMatch(ipAddressFromList);
}
```

Comment: He probably also should replace `.` with `\.` to escape it and treat it literally.

Comment: @user3185569 Tested, working, well done, thank you :)

Comment: This is a wrong answer since `"[0-255]"` matches zero, one, two or five.

Comment: Careful, `[0-255]` doesn't match the range of numbers from 0 to 255!

Comment: It matches a single character which is either '0', '1', '2' or '5'. The '1' is matched because it is include in the character range '0-2' which is part of the character class

Comment: A @WiktorStribiżew says, `[0-255]` matches the characters `0` to `2` plus `5` plus `5`, ie it is equivalent to `[0125]`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a more robust version that does not break if the user input contains Regex metacharacters such as `\`, or unmatched parenthesis:

```
public static bool IpAddressMatchUserInput(string userInput, string ipAddressFromList)
{
    // escape the user input. If user input contains e.g. an unescaped 
    // single backslash we might get an ArgumentException when not escaping
    var escapedInput = Regex.Escape(userInput);

    // replace the wildcard '*' with a regex pattern matching 1 to 3 digits
    var inputWithWildcardsReplaced = escapedInput.Replace("\\*", @"\d{1,3}");

    // require the user input to match at the beginning of the provided IP address
    var pattern = new Regex("^" + inputWithWildcardsReplaced);

    return pattern.IsMatch(ipAddressFromList);
}
```